# Scrolling Failed on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Just working on a test website [1] which needs to scroll on mobile but for some reason it doesnt work. Any help is appreciated.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .title1 {
        font-size: 145px!important;
        line-height: 12vh!important;
        text-align: right;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 170px!important;
        color: #e8e8e8!important;
        margin-top: 340px!important;
        margin-right: -80px!important;
        font-weight: 900!important;
    }

    .title2, .title2, .title4{
        font-size: 10vh!important;
        width: 80%;
        line-height: 11vh!important;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 200px!important;
        margin-left: 60px!important;
        text-align: left!important;
        color: #205545!important;
    }

    #contain-side {
        width: 95%!important;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 93px!important;
    }

    #side-text #side-text3{
        float: right;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 5.5vh;
        text-align: left!important;
        color: black;
        padding-top: 0px!important; 
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        font-size: 33px!important;
        letter-spacing: -0.8px;
    }
}
```

I've checked everything. There is no overflow property, still it's not scrolling on mobile.

Please help-out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should paste your HTML code out, otherwise another cannot analyse what's wrong in your page. At least you should show us the page structure.

I have edited a blank page according to your CSS classes. I hope that I understand your intentions correctly. The following page structure works fine for me. It works on my Huawei and Galexy devices. I hope it can help you a little bit. regards!

[image]

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="contain-side">
        <div id="side-text">
            <div class="title1">title1</div>
            <div class="title2">
                title2
                <div class="title4">title4</div>
            </div>
            text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
            text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
            <div id="side-text3">
                text3<br>text3<br>text3<br>
                text3<br>text3<br>text3<br>
                text3<br>text3<br>text3<br>
                text3<br>text3<br>text3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```